# Django - Create a drop-down list from database data

Tags: django

There is a model field, `city`, it is filled manually when creating the 
**object**.

There is a field in the search form, `city`. In **views.py** it looks like this:

**views.py:**

```
  if 'city' in request.GET:
        city = request.GET['city']
        if city:
            queryset_list = queryset_list.filter(city__iexact=city)
```

**template.html:**

```
<div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
    <label class="sr-only">City</label>
    <input type="text" name="city" class="form-control" placeholder="City">
</div>
```

If you enter the name of the city, objects with that name will be selected. It works correctly, but it’s inconvenient.

I want the city not to be entered, but selected from the list. This list should be automatically collected from the fields city.
How can this be implemented? Thank!

Comment: you mean you want a drop down list populated with all cities?

Comment: **adnanmuttaleb**, Hello! Exactly. Cities of those objects that are on the site

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have not included enough details about your models, but you can get what you using something like that:

Your view:

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def myview(request):
    #get your list of cities you may also do some filtering 
    cities = [obj.city for obj in YourModel.objects.all()]
    return render(request, 'cities_template.html', {'cities': cities})
```

your template (cities_template.html):

```
<select>
{% for city in cities %}
    <option value={{city}}>{{city}}</li>
{% endfor %}
</select>
```

If you provide more details, I may help you better, cheers.

Comment: **adnanmuttaleb**, thanks! But, this is not quite right. Your example takes objects from a `city` model.
The `city` is not a model, this is a `field` in model. I need to collect data from these `fields`, and present them in a drop-down list. **I apologize if I was incomprehensible.**

Comment: I have edited the answer @I.Z. Unfortunately your question is a little incomplete, if you provide more details others will be able to help you better.

Comment: Excellent! It works! May I ask another question? How to sort correctly if there are three models and all the data needs to be put in one list? Thank!

Comment: You are welcome @I.Z., I did not understand you well, I prefer you to post a new question  with all necessary details, and hopefully me and the community will answer you. cheers.

Comment: Also if  you find the solution correct, please do not forget to mark it as correct.